# MenuItem setShowAsAction() not working, or just after pausing

Tags: android, popupmenu

I try to show my MenuItem text and its Icon at the same time and I am creating the menu programmatically. The text gets viewed, but not the icons.

If I keep the app running and go to HomeScreen and tab in again the menu is still open, but then the icons and text are correctly shown...

This is a snippet from my own PopupMenu class

I tried this:

```
Menu menu = getMenu();
sub1 = menu.addSubMenu(0, 0, 0, "Groups");   

for(int i=0; i< tags.size();i++){
        String tag = tags.get(i);                
        MenuItem sub1Item = mGroups.add(3, i,i, tag );

        sub1Item.setIcon(ImageManager.getSymbolDrawable(mActivity, ImageManager.group_symbol_ids[i]));
        sub1Item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    }

MenuItem sub2 = menu.add(1, 1, 1, "Ignore Groups");

sub2.setIcon(R.drawable.ignore_groups_symbol);
sub2.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
```

Hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sub1Item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what this is doing?

Comment: Doesn't work... Not programmatically, neither in xml :(

Answer (score 0):

Could be that the menu needs to be restarted - try adding:

getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu ();

Answer (score 0):

You need to split:

```
item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
```

Into:

```
item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
```